# iBooks widget methods for starting/stopping media?

Tags: html, widget, ibooks

I have an HTML5 widget for iBooks that is used to embed video from external sites.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <iframe id="videoLoadsHere" src="http://www.embeddedvideo.blah">
      </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have 2 problems:

1) iframe remains blank w/o an internet connection. Is there any way to access native device info about connectivity from within a widget (like Phonegap does, but w/o having to import a ton of extra code?)

2) The video continues playing after closing the widget & needs to be stopped manually (unless you move 2 pages away). I'd like it to stop playing & reset when the widget is dismissed, but there doesn't seem to be any way to intercept that user action. How can I tell when a widget is open/closed?

I already tried importing AppleWidget.js in the HTML `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="AppleClasses/AppleWidget.js"> </script>
```

And then also within the head tag handle the methods:

```
    widget.pauseAudioVisual = function() {

         //allegedly called when the widget is dismissed, 
but this is not the case as far as I can tell

    }
```

and

```
widget.didEnterWidgetMode = function(){

         //allegedly called not when first opening a widget, 
         but when re-opening it as a way to resume or reload.

}
```

Neither of those methods ever seem to get called, and there's no way to alert/log anything from within iBooks.

I replicated this guy's experiment exactly, but it didn't work.
https://github.com/miguel/iBooks-Author-widget-events/blob/master/we.wdgt/main.html

I haven't been able to find any other documentation specific to iBooks or any other "widget" methods. Apple's docs all deal with Dashcode & desktop widgets, and don't seem to apply.

Anybody have any references for how to communicate between an HTML5 widget and an iBook? Is there any API? Some window.widget object with known methods?

Thanks!